# Capella M2DOC generation based on selected model entity

Tags: m2doc

I am attempting to generate a m2doc template that generates a common documentation for logical components within the model. I would like to be able to select a Logical component within the model and then use the m2doc tool to generate documentation about the selected element based on the pre-defined template.

Looking at the [m2doc documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueuj6.png) and using the m2doc interpreter I am able to use the `selection` command to gather information about the selected object, e.g. `selection.name` returns the name of the element that is selected within the current diagram (in Capella).

I am however unable to access this variable when using it within the word template. Within the m2doc word template I have tried using `{ m:selection.name }` which produces the following error: `<---Couldn't find the 'selection' variable`

How do you access the "selection" variable from within the m2doc template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection variable is only available form the [M2Doc interpreter view](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/#m2doc-interpreter-view) for testing purpose.

The first method could be to [initialize a .genconf file](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/#initializing-a-generation-configuration) and set a variable to the selected element. But it's not convenient.

If you are familiar with Eclipse plugins, you can contribute a [contextual menu](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html#tutorial-commands-and-context-menus) to Eclipse. In the handler of your corresponding command, you can launch the [generation programmatically](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/#using-m2doc-programmatically).